# ¿ como cambio el color de una celda de una jTable?

Tags: java, jtable

he estado investigando el como hacerlo, pero lo unico que encuentro en crear otra clase extendiendo de DefaultTableCellRenderer pero el problema que tengo es que ya tengo el codigo que crea la tabla hecho, la pregunta es si quiero que el fondo de una celda especifica de la tabla tenga un background de color gris como seria, o necesariamente hay que hacerlo creando una clase extendiendo DefaultTableCellRenderer.
la idea es cambiar el color usando un metodo algo como jTable1.setcolor o algo asi. pasa que en mi codigo tengo que mostrar los datos mayores y menores de la tabla cambiando de color el fondo de ellos entonces lo que quiero es cambiar el background de la celda en la tabla que obtengo cual es la celda despues de revisar cuales son los datos que debo cambiarles el color

Comment: Para que la comunidad entienda mejor tu pregunta, debes lees [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una clase que se encargue de realizar la misma tal como se muestra en este ejemplo:

```
public class EditorCeldas extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{
int Row,Columns;
public void setRow(int Row){
    this.Row=Row;
}
public void setColumns(int Columns){
    this.Columns=Columns;
}
public EditorCeldas() {
    setOpaque(true); // Permite que se vea el color en la celda del JLabel
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if((row == Row) && (column == Columns)){
    setBackground(Color.red); // Una condicion arbitraria solo para pintar el JLabel que esta en la celda.
    setText(String.valueOf(value)); // Se agrega el valor que viene por defecto en la celda
}
if((row != Row)&& (column==Columns)){
    setBackground(Color.white); // Una condicion arbitraria solo para pintar el JLabel que esta en la celda.
    setText(String.valueOf(value)); // Se agrega el valor que viene por defecto en la celda
}
     }
    return this;
}

}
```

Luego aplicamos esta clase a la columna de interés de la tabla

```
TableColumn columna = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);// selecciono la columna que me interesa de la tabla
EditorCeldas TableCellRenderer = new EditorCeldas();
TableCellRenderer.setColumns(column); //se le da por parametro la columna que se quiere modificar
TableCellRenderer.setRow(Row);//se le da por parametro la fila que se quiere modificar
columna.setCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer); // le aplico la edicion
```

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, probe lo que me dijiste pero borro los datos que ya estaban en una columna de la tabla, lo que buscaba era cambiar el color de un celda especifica.

Comment: Ya hice la modificación para evitar ese detalle usando setText. Recuerda que la celda es un JLabel así que puedes hacer lo que necesites con sus propiedades